# Dividing fourier transform by factor n

Tags: python, fft

I have a problem with the fast fourier transform in python. I would like to extract the low and high frequency power of a signal. I have seen the following example:

```
Y = np.fft.fft(signal)/n #Calculate FFT
Y = Y[range(n/2)] #Return one side of the FFT
lf = np.trapz(abs(Y[(frq>=0.04) & (frq<=0.15)]))
hf = np.trapz(abs(Y[(frq>=0.16) & (frq<=0.5)])) #Do the same for 0.16-0.5Hz (HF)
```

`signal` is just a an array of values (Let's say 10000 values).

The problem here is that I don't see what `n` should be. Should `n` just be the length of `signal`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, n should not always be the length of the signal.  n is the length of the FFT, which is determined by the frequency resolution and time localization required, which may also depend on the stationarity and/or other characteristics of the signal, as well as whether any windowing or zero-padding is to be used.